# Remove group membership in AD Powershell script

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to remove the groups in the "member of" section of users in a dead accounts OU.

The script runs and receives no errors, but the items in the list have not changed at all.

```
#Choose Organizational Unit
$SearchBase = "OU=Dead Accounts,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=COM"
#Choose filtering parameters
$disabledaccounts = $SearchBase.children  
#Search through each item and perform x
foreach ($userObject in $disabledaccounts){  
        foreach ($group in $userObject.memberof)  
            {  
                $group = [ADSI]"LDAP://$group"  
                $group.remove("LDAP://$($userobject.distinguishedName)")   
            }}
```

Doesn't seem to be working in my environment, though.

What is an easier way to write this, and can someone explain the bottom part? (group = [ADSI]"LDAP://$group" etc..)

Comment: What exactly is not working? Can you be more specific?

Comment: You're doing this the hard way. I would download the remote server administration tools which includes the Active Directory Powershell Module. This includes the Remove-AdGroupMember cmdlet.

Comment: Nathan Rice, I run the script and it does not work at the deletion part.

Comment: I have the AD Powershell Module, but to be clear I am attempting to remove all the groups from the user profile in the "member of" section.

Comment: Be specific. Are you receiving an error? Is it erroring at a line number? What do you mean "it's not working"? This is not enough information to help you solve your problem. Do you take your car to your mechanic and say, "the car isn't working" and then walk away assuming he will fix the car? No you explain what exactly is happening in as much detail as you can what the problem is so he can help you solve your problem. Please amend your question with some detail using the "edit" link at the bottom of your post.

Comment: Sorry about that, No errors at all, the script runs fine, which is scary I suppose. Looking at the "member of" section shows that nothing has changed. I don't think there is a way to see where it goes wrong since it doesn't... but is there any way I should word that in my questions for the future?

Comment: Is that the entire script? You set `$SearchBase` to a string, then reference the Children property of it, which doesn't exist, so `$disabledaccounts` is `$null`, and then you try to update the groups for all accounts in... nothing? The script does nothing, because as it stands there is nothing for it to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's use the AD cmdlets for this, shall we? First we define where it's going to look, which you actually did you just never applied it anywhere...

```
#Choose Organizational Unit
$SearchBase = "OU=Dead Accounts,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=COM"
```

Then we get a list of users that are located there (make sure to include the `MemberOf` property!):

```
$Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties MemberOf
```

Now let's loop through those users, and for each group in their MemberOf property we'll remove the user from that group (the `-Confirm:$false` switch stops it from prompting you for every single removal... kind of vital for a script like this):

```
ForEach($User in $Users){
    $User.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Member $User -Confirm:$false
}
```

We put it all together and we get:

```
#Choose Organizational Unit
$SearchBase = "OU=Dead Accounts,DC=domain,DC=domain,DC=COM"
$Users = Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase $SearchBase -Properties MemberOf
ForEach($User in $Users){
    $User.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Member $User -Confirm:$false
}
```

Comment: This is perfect! Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for breaking it down and explaining each section. I knew I was grabbing the right content, but when it came to execution it seemed to be doing something else, since it still worked. Thank you!